# Cookie isn't setting, but i allow cookies

Tags: php

I am trying the Post-Redirect-Get pattern.

Here are my custom functions

```
<?php
function ReadCookieMessage()
{
    if (($_COOKIE["c"]) && ($_COOKIE["t"]))
    {
        $message = $_COOKIE["t"];
        $message = htmlspecialchars($message);
        if ($_COOKIE["c"] == "r")
        {
            $cssclass = 'error_msg';
        }
        else if ($_COOKIE["c"] == "g")
        {
            $cssclass = 'success_msg';
        }
        setcookie("c", "", time()-3600);
        setcookie("t", "", time()-3600);
        return '<div class="' . $cssclass . '">' . $message .'</div>';
    }
}
?>
<?php
function SetCookieMessage($c,$t)
{
    setcookie("c",$c, time()+3600);
    setcookie("t",$t, time()+3600);
}
?>
```

I do `SetCookieMessage("g","Your password has been changed, you may now login again");` on my change password page.

Then i do

> echo ReadCookieMessage();

on my login page. I am not sure whats up. setcookie works when i set the r cookie if they check remember when they login. I also tired

```
setcookie("c","g", time()+3600);
setcookie("t","Your password has been changed, you may now login again", time()+3600);
```

in replacement for the `SetCookieMessage` function.

Not sure if

```
if ($SqlChangePass)
                {
                    session_unset();
                    session_destroy();
                    setcookie("r", "", time()-3600);
                    SetCookieMessage("g","Your password has been changed, you may now login again");
                    header("Location: /login");
                }
```

will be any helpful to you. Its in the changepassword script.

Php isn't giving me any errors. The goal of the functions is to set a message color(r means red and g means green) and text. Then take them to another page and read the message. The page it goes to isn't showing any sort of a message.

Comment: Did you check your browser, if the cookies are actually stored? Try a `print_r( $_COOKIE )` on the page where you want to check the values. Also in general, test the existance of the variables with `isset( $_COOKIE['c'] )` (at the top of the first function).

Comment: print_r( $_COOKIE ) comes back with __cfduid and PHPSESSID

Comment: Hmm, then obviously the cookies are not set correctly... Because I'm out of ideas, can you check the return value of the `setcookie` function?

Comment: I put SetCookieMessage("g","Your password has been changed, you may now login again");
  echo ReadCookieMessage(); on a test page. If i load the page, i see nothing. If i refresh the page again, i see a message. If i refresh again, i don't see the message.... So not sure if this helps any on debugging.

Comment: I just commented out setcookie("c", "", time()-3600); and setcookie("t", "", time()-3600);  in the read function.... It worked. Is it possible to show the message and delete the cookie after or should i just let it expire on its own(don't really want to do it this way)?

Comment: `setcookie` sets the cookies in the response of the page, so they are available with the next request. As such, that behaviour is normal. Guess there is something wrong with the way you call your custom function then...

Comment: Huh, did you call the read function somewhere before, like on the change password page as well? Otherwise there shouldn't be a problem with deleting the cookies *after* you read them...

Comment: I only called the read on the login page... So i have no clue why. Didn't call the read function on the change password page.

Comment: I think i am just going to dump this idea. just send ?c=g&t=msg with each request.

Comment: I decided to convert it to use sessions. It works! I just have to create a session after i kill it. But this will be used also mostly when they are logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if I get it right you execute as follows:

```
<?php
SetCookieMessage("something","here");
ReadCookieMessage();
?>
```

If this is the case, that would be normal behaviour.
Cookies are sent along with the result page in the page headers.
So you would only be able to read cookies on a next request.

e.g. First Request:

1. Do stuff
2. Place Cookie
3. Return result page

Second request could be:

1. Do stuff
2. Read cookie
3. return result page

You can read more about cookies on Wikipedia: [Wikipedia page about HTTP Cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)
I quote:

> The cookie is sent as a field in the header of the HTTP response by a web server to a web browser and then sent back unchanged by the browser each time it accesses that server.

I hope I understood your question correctly. And that my answer helps.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, then the cookies are (supposed to be) set on the password-reset page, and read on the login page.

Answer (score 0):

*"I put SetCookieMessage("g","Your password has been changed, you may now login again"); echo ReadCookieMessage(); on a test page."*

As Bart said, you can't set a cookie and check it on the same page.

*"If i load the page, i see nothing. If i refresh the page again, i see a message. If i refresh again, i don't see the message"*

On you case, that's what is happening:

- You set the cookie, they're correctly set. After you set the cookie, you try to check it, but the script will not be able to see it because it was not set when it started
- You reload the page, the script can now read the cookie and will display your message. But in your code, you tell the browser to expiry the cookies on ReadCookieMessage() when you set it into the past (-3600).
- You reload the page, and set the cookies again and it start all over because the previous cookie has now been unset.

Check the link Bart provided! :)